# Programmatically Add UITableView to UITabBar

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a TabBar App. I have created a UITableView class called "Schedule" that has a matching Nib. I want to add Schedule to the TabBar, but I do not want to do it through Interface Builder. When I add it Programmatically, I see the TableView, but it is blank. I have added some NSLogs to Schedule.m and the class does not appear to be called. The Nib and the Schedule Class are connected properly. I figure I am doing something wrong in the code where I am adding the UITableView to the TabBar:

```
// Create View Controllers
UITableViewController *scheduleViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Schedule" bundle:nil]; 

// Create UITabBarItems
UITabBarItem *scheduleTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Schedule" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar.png"] tag:0];

scheduleViewController.tabBarItem = scheduleTabBarItem; 

// Create Array of View Controllers
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:scheduleNavigationController, nil];

// Add View Controllers to TabBar
[tabBarController setViewControllers:items animated:NO];    

// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating a `UITableViewController`, which does not contain any code to fill the table view with data. So where do you suppose the data for the table should come from? If you have written a custom UITableViewController subclass for it, you have to instantiate this subclass here (and set it as the File's Owner in your NIB file).

Comment: It is set as the file's owner in the Nib... I thought that would be enough to tell it where to get the data from.

Comment: Thank you , that was the kick in the brain I needed. I changed it to be Schedule *scheduleViewController = [[Schedule alloc] initWithNib:@"Schedule" bundle:nil];